# What to call the opposite of the diameter of a metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology

The diameter of a metric space is the maximum distance between any two points.  Is there a standard term for the minimum distance between any two distinct points?  What about the ratio of the maximum to the minimum?

Comment: The diameter is defined as a supremum, not as a maximum: $$\text{diam}(X) = \text{sup}\{d(x,y) \,\bigm|\, x,y \in X\}$$ For example, if your metric space is an open ball in the plane then the maximum does not exist but the supremum doe and, as one expects, is equal to two times the radius of that ball.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a name for that quantity itself.

However, if you replace the minimum by an infimum then there is a name for metric spaces $X$ such that the quantity
$$\text{inf}\{d(x,y) \, \bigm| \, x \ne y \in X\}
$$
is nonzero: they are called *uniformly discrete*.

Although there is not a huge literature on uniformly discrete metric spaces (in sharp contrast to the ubiquity of the concept of "diameter"), I know of a couple of places where uniformly discrete metric spaces are very important, in particular Kevin Whyte's thesis where he proves a geometric version of the Von Neumann conjecture:

Whyte, Kevin, "Amenability, bi-Lipschitz equivalence, and the von Neumann conjecture", Duke Math. J. 99 (1999), no. 1, 93–112.

Comment: To add to this, I've found some papers that call the ratio the *aspect ratio* of a metric space (e.g. [On Metric Ramsey Type Phenomenon](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwig6OD3l8TUAhVOyGMKHUMoDhgQFggqMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.huji.ac.il%2F~nati%2FPAPERS%2Framsey_l2.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGhoJeFRYKrigrfbBdgNMXKHnjJ-A&sig2=C-iUmUq1MEeaFIrN5cOaqg)).  None of these papers explicitly name the infimum though, so I think there's probably not a standard name for it.